# Anyone have any idea why this PBR texture is having weird shading and lighting effects on my plane?

Tags: texturing, lighting

I put the normal map image through a normal map node, and it seemed to have these weird issues:
https://gyazo.com/84ab56b0c88554d72c98e1aa37a3de49
When I just took the image and put it straight into the normal input, it didn't have this problem at all.
My node setup looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/37dd2f17f6f4c91e3a015c21e2f97ffd
I tried looking around to see if anyone else has had this problem, but I couldln't find anything except one person who had an issue, but theirs was different in that they UV unwrapped their mesh, while the thing that I'm applying the texture to is just a plane: 4 vertices, not subdivided at all.

Update: I ditched the normal map and instead used a displacement map with a displacement node, but it works, but I'd still like to know what the problem was and how to fix it in the future

Comment: please use the tools from this site to load images, so that users don't have to go to links to understand the question.

Comment: How to upload an image to a post - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the Color Space for your Normal Map image texture to Non-Color. You will want to do this for your roughness map as well. Only Basecolor, Subsurface Color, Emission, and Ambient Occlusion use a "colored" Color-Space such as sRGB or Linear, all the rest (Roughness, Metallic, Height(Displacement), Normal Map, etc..) use Non-Color space.

[image: PBR]

Comment: Ah, thanks this fixed the problem.